# logrotate on ubuntu 20.04.4 won't run *my config* in systemd

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I have a a few processes that output logs to `/var/tmp/` and `/tmp/`. I am trying to get logrotate to work on them using a file I have put in `/etc/logrotate.d/`.
One set of files is generated by `rsyslog` utility (where I capture the output and act on it on a separate script)

For the life of me , I can't figure out why `logrotate` in `systemd` never runs *my config*. Manual running always works with no errors.

```
# laxfw logrotate files - an addition to rsyslog logrotate

sharedscripts

/var/tmp/laxfw.log
/var/tmp/laxauth.log
/tmp/laxfw.log
/tmp/laxauth.log
/var/log/laxfw.log
/var/log/laxauth.log
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
#   delaycompress
    compress
    su syslog syslog
    create 0664 syslog syslog
    prerotate
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.prerotate.sh "$1"
    endscript 
    postrotate
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.postrotate.sh "$1"
    endscript
}

/tmp/laxabuse.log
/var/tmp/laxabuse.log
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
#   delaycompress
    compress
    su root root
    prerotate
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.prerotate.sh "$1"
    endscript 
    postrotate
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.postrotate.sh "$1"
    endscript
}
```

I have tried moving the logs to different directories. I have changed the apparmor permissons to these files. I have added prerotate and posrotate scripts that will capture *attempts*

Running with `--debug` or `--verbose` yields nothing I can find.

What am I missing?

-- EDIT --
Relevant output for `--debug` option:

```
logrotate --debug /etc/logrotate.conf
...
reading config file laxfw.logrotate
...
rotating pattern: /var/tmp/laxfw.log
/var/tmp/laxauth.log
/tmp/laxfw.log
/tmp/laxauth.log
/var/log/laxfw.log
/var/log/laxauth.log
 after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 104 and egid to 110
considering log /var/tmp/laxfw.log
  Now: 2022-04-03 14:08
  Last rotated at 2022-04-01 09:28
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/tmp/laxauth.log
  Now: 2022-04-03 14:08
  Last rotated at 2022-04-01 09:28
  log needs rotating
considering log /tmp/laxfw.log
  log /tmp/laxfw.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /tmp/laxauth.log
  log /tmp/laxauth.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/log/laxfw.log
  log /var/log/laxfw.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/log/laxauth.log
  log /var/log/laxauth.log does not exist -- skipping
rotating log /var/tmp/laxfw.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20220403'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.7.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.6.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.5.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.4.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.3.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.2.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.1.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log.0.gz to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
log /var/tmp/laxfw.log.8.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
rotating log /var/tmp/laxauth.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20220403'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.7.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.6.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.5.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.4.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.3.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.2.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.1.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log.0.gz to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
log /var/tmp/laxauth.log.8.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
running prerotate script
running script with arg /var/tmp/laxfw.log
/var/tmp/laxauth.log
/tmp/laxfw.log
/tmp/laxauth.log
/var/log/laxfw.log
/var/log/laxauth.log
: "
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.prerotate.sh "$1"
"
renaming /var/tmp/laxfw.log to /var/tmp/laxfw.log.1
creating new /var/tmp/laxfw.log mode = 0664 uid = 104 gid = 110
renaming /var/tmp/laxauth.log to /var/tmp/laxauth.log.1
creating new /var/tmp/laxauth.log mode = 0664 uid = 104 gid = 110
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/tmp/laxfw.log
/var/tmp/laxauth.log
/tmp/laxfw.log
/tmp/laxauth.log
/var/log/laxfw.log
/var/log/laxauth.log
: "
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.postrotate.sh "$1"
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
switching euid to 0 and egid to 0

rotating pattern: /tmp/laxabuse.log
/var/tmp/laxabuse.log
 after 1 days (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /tmp/laxabuse.log
  log /tmp/laxabuse.log does not exist -- skipping
considering log /var/tmp/laxabuse.log
  Now: 2022-04-03 14:08
  Last rotated at 2022-04-01 09:28
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/tmp/laxabuse.log, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20220403'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.7.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.6.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.5.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.4.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.3.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.2.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.1.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.0.gz to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
log /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.8.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
running prerotate script
running script with arg /tmp/laxabuse.log
/var/tmp/laxabuse.log
: "
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.prerotate.sh "$1"
"
renaming /var/tmp/laxabuse.log to /var/tmp/laxabuse.log.1
creating new /var/tmp/laxabuse.log mode = 0644 uid = 0 gid = 0
running postrotate script
running script with arg /tmp/laxabuse.log
/var/tmp/laxabuse.log
: "
        /usr/local/laxfw/laxfw.postrotate.sh "$1"
"
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
```

The existing `.#.gz` files were created by running by hand